# edit cookies to handle expiry date

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to make script to keep checking on this website "https://stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-linen", I noticed that the response varies when cookies are used, however I tried hard coding the cookies but they expire or fail after certain amount of time

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

response = requests.get('https://stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-linen',headers=headers)
```

the response is I want should contain the "main price" and "size:price" i.e the one with cookies used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a request to the actual page and parsing the data, have you considered using their API?

https://stockx.com/api/browse?&_search=YB350V2-LN&dataType=product

You can get the title and sale data from that using the headers you have provided.

Edit:

If you inspect the page you have linked, you will see that each size has a SKU. You can make a request to this URL to get the latest sale data.

https://stockx.com/api/products/7610eeb7-38d6-44fe-b00c-585311f120d7/activity?state=480&currency=USD

Reference:
https://medium.com/@thewillmundy/stockx-sneaker-data-in-three-simple-steps-8977d0016b80

Comment: is there a way to also get size/price (for each size there is a price) ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You will need to build a list of possible SKUs